# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input for large data request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data via API post request from the nodeJS server querying a MySQL database, if I set the query limit to 1000000 entries, everything works fine, however, when I increase the limit to 2000000  I get "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input", and if I remove the limit completely the react app interface crashes AND I get the following error "Something went wrong while displaying this webpage Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT".

below is the server-side code :

```
app.post('api/results', (req, res) => {

res.set('content-type', 'application/json');

const startdate = req.body.StartDate;

const enddate = req.body.EndDate;

console.log('start =', startdate);

console.log('end =', enddate);

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  let queryString =
    'SELECT table1.*,table2.* FROM  'table2'  INNER JOIN  'table1' ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table2.date BETWEEN ? AND ?';
  let filter = [startdate, enddate];
  var query = connection.query(queryString, filter);
  query
    .on('fields', function (fields) {})

    .on('result', function (row) {
      const FormattedRow = FormatRowDate(row);
      return FormattedRow;
    })
    .stream({ highWaterMark: 50000 })
    .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
    .pipe(res)
    .on('finish', function () {
      console.log('Data Retrieved Successfully');
      connection.release();
    });
});
```

The client-side API request is below :

```
const StartDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CustomStartDate"));
const EndDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CustomEndDate"));
let data = { StartDate: StartDate, EndDate: EndDate };
 const results = await fetch(
  'http://localhost:5000/api/results',
  {
    method: "post", 
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
)
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then(res => {
    return res;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    error.response = {
      status: 0,
      statusText:
        "Cannot connect. Please make sure you are connected to internet."
    };
    throw error;
  });
```

is there a way to fetch all database entries without applying the limit?